# Mostrar Post en estado Borrador con permalinks /%postname%/ en WordPress

Tags: wordpress, post

Saludos Comunidad, quiero mostrar comentarios con la plantilla single.php teniendo el permalink /%postname%/ ya que los post publicados quedan con el nombre asignado pero al querer desplegar los post con estado borrador me genera la URL ?post_type=comentarios&p=1736 un error 404, es posible mostrar este tipo de post de otra forma ?

Mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El `%postname%` corresponde al campo `post_slug` de la tabla `wp_posts`y este campo se calcula con la función [`wp_unique_post_slug()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug) **cuando cambias el estatus a publicado**.

En esta [respuesta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41588/how-to-get-the-clean-permalink-in-a-draft) proponen esta función:

```
global $post;
if (in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft'))) {
    $my_post = clone $post;
    $my_post->post_status = 'published';
    $my_post->post_name = sanitize_title($my_post->post_name ? $my_post->post_name : $my_post->post_title, $my_post->ID);
    $permalink = get_permalink($my_post);
} else {
    $permalink = get_permalink();
}
```

Esta función la puedes colocar en tu archivo `functions.php` siguiendo un tutorial como [este](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-custom-shortcut-links-to-wordpress-toolbar/).

Comment: No me funciona esta solución, me genera la siguiente advertencia : Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in functions.php on line 786 .